# Memory Issue in C++ - UNINITIALIZED READ: reading register eax

Tags: c++, dr-memory

After declaring a default constructor for this templated program I am working on:

```
template<typename T>
Set<T>::Set()
    : size(0), capacity(8) {
    //allocate new array
    items = new T[capacity];
}
```

I have a relatively inconspicuous function `contains` that tests for whether or not `items` contains a specific item in it.

```
template<typename T>
bool Set<T>::contains(const T& item) const {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (this->items[i] == item)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}
```

It works fine when I call it in certain locations such as this function that reads through `items` and only adds an item if there is no other copy (part of our assignment specifications):

```
template<typename T>
void Set<T>::add(const T& item) {
    if (this->contains(item) == 0) {
        grow();
        items[size++] = item;
    }
}
```

But when I call it when attempting to overload the operator `==`, I get the error in the title when I run it through DRMemory

```
template<typename T>
bool Set<T>::operator==(const Set<T>& other) const {
    int count = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
        if (this->contains(other.items[i])) {
           count++;
        }
    }
    if (count == size)
        return true;
    return false;
}
```

Comment: Did you respect the [rule of 3/5/0](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three)? If not, you may have UB in your code when copying or assigning.

Comment: @FrançoisAndrieux Yeah, I have a copy constructor, assignment operator, and destructor that all work fine and do deep copies/manage memory and pass the unit tests my instructor provided.

Comment: In `operator==()` there is no check that `size == other.size`.   If `size > other.size` then the loop accesses elements of `other.items` past the end.  Undefined behaviour.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) {
    if (this->contains(other.items[i])) {
       count++;
    }
}
```

`size` should be `other.size`. Otherwise `other.items[i]` in the loop may be out-of-bounds if `size > other.size`.

Similarly `size` in the later check needs to be `other.size` as well.

On the other hand, you need to add a test for `size == other.size` anyway to make sure that the sets are really equal. If you put that at the beginning, it won't matter whether you use `size` or `other.size` later.

Btw. instead of using `count` to count the identical elements, you can just `return false` as soon as one `.contains` fails.